# Simple division operation returning zero?

Tags: java

What am I missing?

```
float stepSize = 0.0f;
int activeCircleRadius = 10;
int numSteps = 24;

AiLog.v("init activeCircleRadius " + activeCircleRadius + " numSteps "
                + numSteps);
stepSize = activeCircleRadius / numSteps;
AiLog.v("stepSize is " + stepSize);
```

stepSize is always zero in the log after the operation. Does it have to do with dividing a float by an int?

Comment: A `float / int` is a `float`  Given your example doesn't compile, I would check what your code is exactly.

Comment: It compiles. The value of stepSize is just always zero.

Comment: float activeCircleRadius = 10.0; it show typeMismatch error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here both variables are integers so you are performing integer division:

```
activeCircleRadius / numSteps
```

The result of integer division is an integer. The result is truncated.

To fix the problem, change the type of one (or both) variables to a `float`:

```
float stepSize = 0.0f;
float activeCircleRadius = 10;
```

Or add a cast to float in the division expression:

```
stepSize = (float)activeCircleRadius / numSteps;
```

Comment: This was it. I was unaware of integer vs float division

Comment: @Zed Scio: Accept his answer then!

Comment: @ZedScio:  Oh sorry ... thought you'd had enough time :)

Answer (score 3):

Don't do integer division

```
stepSize = activeCircleRadius / (float)numSteps;
```

In summary:  Yes its because you divide activeCircleRadius by an integer.

Answer (score 1):

```
 With all arithmetic operators in Java, the result has the type of the largest operator. For instance: 
- float operator long => float 
- int operator int => int 
- int operator long => long 


float stepSize = 0f;
        float activeCircleRadius = (float) 10.0;
        int numSteps = 24;
        stepSize = activeCircleRadius / numSteps;
```

Comment: This should help the program *compile* but doesn't explain the problem. ;)

Comment: There is no compilation issue anyway. 0 = 0.0f
I have it in the code as 0.0f already, just didn't type it out here that way.

Answer (score 1):

an integer division will give the result as 0.
its 10/24 and not 10.0/24.0.
you need to make one variable as double or float to get non zero answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing an integer division, and hence will not get any decimal places in your answer. Try changing:

```
stepSize = activeCircleRadius / numSteps;
```

to

```
stepSize = activeCircleRadius / (float)numSteps;
```